# How do you generate a hyperlink from a Model in MVC Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, html-helper, razor-declarative-helpers

I want to store website addresses in a table in the database as either "http://some_website.com" or just as "some_website.com". Then in the view I have access to the text through "Model.Website". How can I generate a hyperlink? Is there a helper to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Simply embed the model properties in a hyperlink element appropriately:

```
public class YourModel
{
    public string Href { get; set; }
    public string LinkText { get; set; }
}
```

...

```
<a href="@Model.Href">@Model.LinkText</a>
```